# HighCharts JS Ajax Data Guage

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

Could someone please assist me on modifying the code from HighCharts Angular Gauge demo to load data from a comma-separated values file?

The comma-separated values column should be specifiable. i.e: data[0], data[1], data[2]

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]        
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}, 
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
});
```

An Example of comma-separated values data being loaded into Highcharts Demo - Ajax loaded data, clickable points.

```
 $(function () {

// Register a parser for the American date format used by Google
Highcharts.Data.prototype.dateFormats['m/d/Y'] = {
    regex: '^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2})$',
    parser: function (match) {
        return Date.UTC(+('20' + match[3]), match[1] - 1, +match[2]);
    }
};

// Get the CSV and create the chart
$.get('/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/analytics.csv', function (csv) {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        data: {
            csv: csv
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Daily visits at www.highcharts.com'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
            tickWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3,
                y: -3
            }
        },

        yAxis: [{ // left y axis
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3,
                y: 16,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                }
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }, { // right y axis
            linkedTo: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3,
                y: 16,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                }
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }],

        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                pageOrigin: {
                                    x: this.pageX,
                                    y: this.pageY
                                },
                                headingText: this.series.name,
                                maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+
                                    this.y +' visits',
                                width: 200
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'All visits',
            lineWidth: 4,
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            }
        }, {
            name: 'New visitors'
        }]
    });
});

});
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First of all I see that you have empty series.data which doesn't exists. In case when you download data by ajax, you push your data to series or use i.e setData() / addPoint() functions. All of them are documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

I advice to familiar with article about preprocessing data http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing